# How to create war file if project doesn't have entry point?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war

There is a project in github:
https://github.com/chexagon/redis-session-manager

I downloaded and created jar file via maven. But I must use war file for deploying it to Tomcat and use it in our own application. Because of this project doesn't have web.xml file or any entry point (at least I couldn't find it) I couldn't create war file properly. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are usage instructions right on the linked page. Basically put it into `tomcat/libs` and update tomcat's server configuration to use it as the session manager. This is not deployed as a web application, it is an add-on for Tomcat itself.

Comment: I could test it in local and achieved my goal. But in production I can't add jar files to Tomcat lib folder, because it causes problems. That is why I thought to deploy war file but how you told it is impossible

Comment: No, this is a Tomcat add-on. You need to be able to "mess" with Tomcat itself in order to set this up. The alternative would be to not use the provided Servlet sessions and control state management via Redis in your application code directly.

Answer (score 0):

The software you downloaded is not a web application.  It is a component that can be used as part of a web application.

**Correction** - Actually it is an add-on component / plugin for Tomcat itself ... that allows the session state of web applications to be persisted in Redis.

Turning it into a WAR file won't help.

Even putting it into your application's WAR file won't help.

The JAR file needs to be copied to the tomcat/lib directory.  Then you add a a `<Manager>` element to the `conf/server.xml` file.   The `README.md` file describes the attributes of `<Manager>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I change the application by myself so I will be able to  create proper war file? And if I can do it how to do it :)

Comment: This is not deployed as a web application, it is an add-on for Tomcat itself.

Comment: Thank you very much